# Cardview radius was missing because of hardwareacclerated true

Tags: android, android-cardview, pull-to-refresh, cornerradius

I have a list of card view with pull to refresh functionality. For a custom loading image, I tried to draw on the canvas with the hardwareAccelerated true setting. because of this card view radius was missing. I need hardwareAccelerated true setting and card view radius

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
   xmlns:card_view="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:elevation="8dp" 
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:id="@+id/feat_card_one"
   app:cardElevation="5dp" 
   card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing now?

Comment: Cardview radius was missing. it showing square corners instead of rounded

Comment: Can you post your code please

Comment: I have card view like this.
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/feat_card_one"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
**This is issue only in Android <= lollipop